# List column to display embedded iframe

Tags: sharepoint-online, iframe

Is there a way to embed  on a list item? Like storing the  link in a list rich text column and when the item is opened, it will display the map?

[image]

Comment: Sharepoint online or on-premise?

Comment: SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

Are you using modern lists? An alternative to embedding an iframe could be to use View Formatting. View formatting simply uses JSON and can really improve the design of a SharePoint list.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting

A good example with Google Maps integrated can be found here: 
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples/contact-card-format

Answer (score 0):

Not in SharePoint Online Calculated Columns. They removed the "bug" that we used to use for this.

You should still be able to get there using a workflow, but it may not work on Modern UI pages.
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2018/01/adding-html-to-sharepoint-columns-color.html

Comment: I'm not really using calculated column.  User can just copy and paste the <iframe> from google and I just want the map to be displayed on DispForm.aspx when opened -- rather than displaying the <iframe> text. I've used workflow to insert html code in rich text box, which works on list view, but I can't get it to work with <iframe>

Answer (score 0):

We can add the code below into script editor web part into the DispForm.aspx page to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var $googleMap=$("td.ms-formlabel:contains('Google Map')").next();
    $googleMap.html($googleMap.html().replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;', '>'));     
}); 
</script>
```